# on raspberry 4B in Spyder - IDE Python-scripts can't run or debugged Err: libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

Tags: python, spyder

On my Raspi 4 Mod. B  I've installed Spyder with: sudo apt-get install spyder3. If I now open a Python script in Spyder and want to start it with "FileExecute(F5)" NOTHING happens! Nothing happens with "FileDebugging(CTRL+F5)" either. Nothing is displayed in the console either, neither an error message nor anything that indicates the execution of the script.

Then I have started Spyder from the command line and get the following error-message here:

libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/dock.py", line 243, in install_tab_event_filter
tabbars = self.main.findChildren(QTabBar)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MainWindow has been deleted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/dock.py", line 243, in install_tab_event_filter
tabbars = self.main.findChildren(QTabBar)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MainWindow has been deleted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/dock.py", line 243, in install_tab_event_filter
tabbars = self.main.findChildren(QTabBar)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MainWindow has been deleted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/dock.py", line 243, in install_tab_event_filter
tabbars = self.main.findChildren(QTabBar)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MainWindow has been deleted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/dock.py", line 243, in install_tab_event_filter
tabbars = self.main.findChildren(QTabBar)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MainWindow has been deleted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/dock.py", line 243, in install_tab_event_filter
tabbars = self.main.findChildren(QTabBar)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MainWindow has been deleted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/dock.py", line 243, in install_tab_event_filter
tabbars = self.main.findChildren(QTabBar)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MainWindow has been deleted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/dock.py", line 243, in install_tab_event_filter
tabbars = self.main.findChildren(QTabBar)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MainWindow has been deleted
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("/usr/bin/python3") is still running.
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("/usr/bin/python3") is still running.

Did have anybody an idea where the problem is?